# WordPress - Custom rest routes permission callback and nonce verification

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom wordpress route. I'm setting a nonce that is loaded into js using `wp_localize_script`. Insode the callback of the route I'm checking the nonce in this way

```php
if( !wp_verify_nonce( $request->get_header('X-WP-Nonce'), 'wp_rest' ) ){
 return false;
} else {
// do code stuff and return response
}
```

the nonce is created using `wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')` function. In my custom route callback I'm checking if user is logged in with `is_user_logged_in()` function.

Will this work as expected? I've read that it's best to rely on the `current_user_can()` function, but in my case I have a custom user role where the only permission is `edit_users` and another custom role where the only permission is `read`.

Any suggestion on how to correctly set nonce and permission callback?

Answer (score 2):

Even tho nonce are supposed to be a layer of protection, they're not that secured. Nonces are just an additional filter to prevent empty/dummy request.

Actually nonces are passed to javascript through a simple javascript tag, visible to anyone.
Furthermore, the actual output of the JavaScript `<script>` a tag containing your localization variable occurs at the time that the enqueued script is printed (output/included on the page).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        var Data = {"_my_nonce":"331d2779a3"};
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could generate an array of ids of your custom roles through [`get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) coupled with the user role parameter and compare them to the current user id via [`get_current_user_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/).

```
<?php

$users = get_users(
    array(
        'fields' => 'ID',
        'role' => array(
            'custom_role_one',
            'custom_role_two',
            //...
        ),
    )
);

$nonce = $request->get_header( 'X-WP-Nonce' );

$user_id = get_current_user_id();

if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce ) && in_array( $user_id, $users ) ) {

    return false;

} else {

    //...

};
```

Comment: I know that the nonce will be displayed inside the page into a js tag. Anyway if I get the users id, do I will need to check them inside my callback? The site will have a lot of users so is this a reilable solution? Also what I will set into the `permissions_callback` needed to setup custom routes?

Comment: You could simply compare an array of roles against the current user role through [`current_user_can( 'my-custom-role' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/). With current_user_can() you are able to either use a capability or a role (slug).

Comment: in the documentation is discouraged to use `current_user_can` with a role because the result can be different as expected, but I need to do a test

Comment: discouraged doesn't mean bad, or not secured, it's just regarding the reliability of results when you want to limit capabilities. But in your case you want to limit the access.

Comment: ok, so I assume that the function will not fail to check for the role who can call the route